# How to remove ?wp-mce-4103-20162941

Tags: php, html

After check GT Metrix I found Remove query strings from static resources results is 50% and then found that's because some URL have ?wp-mce-4103-20162941 and no plugin can remove this so can use a code like this:

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
$parts = explode( '?wp-mce-', $src );
return $parts[0];
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```